# Regarding executing data flow tasks in a specific order in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis, sql-server-2016, data-migration, flat-file

I created 4 **Data Flow Tasks** as shown in the image in which order I want them to run:

1. Customers
2. Locations
3. Orders
4. Items

[image]

Each data task flow consists of:

1. Flat File data source
2. Data Conversion
3. OLE DB Destination

[image]

When I run, according to the **Execution Results tab** in the image, not in the order I wanted but:

1. Customers
2. Items
3. Locations
4. Orders

The execution completes successfully though. I was able to check all data successfully inserted into DB.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Does sequence of tables migration matter when tables have foreign keys?
2. If yes, then why the above execution didn't throw any errors?
3. How to specify the order of execution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order you've specified is the order in which it has actually run. The Execution Results tab is showing them alphabetically.

If you'd like to see the order and prove it to yourself, add some tasks in the sequence to write to a table with datetimes in, or make or inspect a log (using the SSIS Catalog if you're using a Project deployment, or a Log Provider if using Package deployment).

Answer (score 0):

The order is exactly the way you set. but If its important to you to be sure its in specific order, you can set the **Constraint**  to **Completion**.

i this way the second will not start till the first complete.